# How to add jquery Datepicker to Odoo v10?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, odoo, qweb

I am extending website_sale.checkout template and want to add $('#datepicker').datepicker(), how to do that in assets.js?

```
    <template id="checkout_add_delivery" inherit_id="website_sale.checkout">
        <xpath expr="//a[@class='btn btn-default mb32']" position="replace">
            <form action="/shop/payment" method="post" class="s_website_form form-horizontal container-fluid mt32"
                  enctype="multipart/form-data" data-force_action="sale.order" data-model_name="sale.order" data-success_page="/shop/payment">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" t-att-value="request.csrf_token()"/>
                </div>
            </form>
        </xpath>
    </template>

    <template id="assets_backend" name="custom assets" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
        <xpath expr="." position="inside">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/sales_order_extension/static/src/js/assets.js"></script>
        </xpath>
    </template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
<template id="checkout_add_delivery" inherit_id="website_sale.checkout">
        <xpath expr="//a[@class='btn btn-default mb32']" position="replace">
            <form action="/shop/payment" method="post" class="s_website_form form-horizontal container-fluid mt32"
                  enctype="multipart/form-data" data-force_action="sale.order" data-model_name="sale.order" data-success_page="/shop/payment">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" t-att-value="request.csrf_token()"/>
                </div>
            </form>
        </xpath>
    </template>

    <template id="assets_backend" name="custom assets" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
        <xpath expr="." position="inside">
        <!-- add this library before your assets.js like i added  -->
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/sales_order_extension/static/src/js/assets.js"></script>
        </xpath>
    </template>
```

Then in your assets.js file add your jquery code also.

```
$(function(){
$('#datepicker').datepicker();
});
```

Comment: Did you check this? @Eimis Genčiauskas

Comment: Yeah, is it enought for js file to have only these three lines? It still doesn't work... @lalithkumar

Comment: you need to add that in your file means you need to add with old code where you want.It is not meaning of only three lines

Comment: You didn't understand me. I added the script source to my view, and the function to my assets.js file. At the moment it has only those three lines. So I am asking if I don't need to configure that file more with odoo syntax to work.